# PHP Move images function

Tags: php, foreach

need help with this.

```
function move_images($dir_source,$dir_target){
    $files = glob($dir_source);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file))
        copy($file,$dir_target.basename($file));
        unlink($file);
    }
    return true;
}
move_images('temp/*','../images/');
```

I got this message:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/scrapboo/public_html/inc/functions.php on line 75

Actually, it's working good when there's a files in "temp" directory. So, how to skip this when temp is empty?

Thanks

Comment: Well $files isn't an array.. Are you sure you directory is correct? And you actually retrieve a list of files?

Comment: check $dir_source, the glob() function is returning something which is not an array nor a loopable object, apparently.

Comment: It's working when there's a files in temp folder. How to skip this when temp is empty?

Comment: @Mikael This shouldn't give you any problems! Then it just wont iterate. (Check if you can read the dir: with `is_readable()`)

Comment: What does `var_dump($files)` gives you?

Comment: @Mikael ^ Means? problem solved? Should I put an answer?

Comment: @Rizier123 Problem SOLVED!! Sure, why not =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, it's working good when there's a files in "temp" directory. So, how to skip this when temp is empty?

No need to check if the directory/array is empty, if it would be it just won't iterate through your foreach loop.

But you have to make sure that your directory is readable, you can check this with [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php).

Comment: Sorry I can't vote you up. I don't have enough reputation =p
Thanks anyway!